# How do I determine how much or little I should limit Nginx RAM use to?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, nginx, memory, server

Currently I'm trying to fix a problem with OOM Kill Process and one of the solutions I've came across is limiting Nginx RAM use by setting client_max_body_size to the value I want it limited to. However, my problem now is trying to figure out exactly or even just roughly what I should be limiting that value to. Does anyone have any ideas on how to figure that out? Any and everything is appreciated. Thank you.

Also, here are the logs from when our server would go down and we have to manually restart it in AWS for it to get going again:

```
Out of memory: kill process 15654 (ruby) score 338490 or a child
Killed process 15654 (ruby) vsz:1353960kB, anon-rss:210704kB, file-rss:0kB
nginx invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_adj=0
nginx cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Pid: 8729, comm: nginx Tainted: G        W   2.6.35.14-97.44.amzn1.x86_64 #1
Call Trace:
[<ffffffff8108e638>] ? cpuset_print_task_mems_allowed+0x98/0xa0
[<ffffffff810bb157>] dump_header.clone.1+0x77/0x1a0
[<ffffffff81318d49>] ? _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x19/0x20
[<ffffffff811ab3af>] ? ___ratelimit+0x9f/0x120
[<ffffffff810bb2f6>] oom_kill_process.clone.0+0x76/0x140
[<ffffffff810bb4d8>] __out_of_memory+0x118/0x190
[<ffffffff810bb5d2>] out_of_memory+0x82/0x1c0
[<ffffffff810beb89>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x689/0x6a0
[<ffffffff810e7864>] alloc_pages_current+0x94/0xf0
[<ffffffff810b87ef>] __page_cache_alloc+0x7f/0x90
[<ffffffff810c15e0>] __do_page_cache_readahead+0xc0/0x200
[<ffffffff810c173c>] ra_submit+0x1c/0x20
[<ffffffff810b9f63>] filemap_fault+0x3e3/0x430
[<ffffffff810d023f>] __do_fault+0x4f/0x4b0
[<ffffffff810d2774>] handle_mm_fault+0x1b4/0xb40
[<ffffffff81007682>] ? check_events+0x12/0x20
[<ffffffff81006f1d>] ? xen_force_evtchn_callback+0xd/0x10
[<ffffffff81007682>] ? check_events+0x12/0x20
[<ffffffff8131c752>] do_page_fault+0x112/0x310
[<ffffffff813194b5>] page_fault+0x25/0x30
Mem-Info:
Node 0 DMA per-cpu:
CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
CPU    1: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
CPU    2: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
CPU    3: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Node 0 DMA32 per-cpu:
CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  35
CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  30
CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Node 0 Normal per-cpu:
CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 202
CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  30
CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  59
CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 140
active_anon:3438873 inactive_anon:284496 isolated_anon:0
active_file:0 inactive_file:62 isolated_file:64
unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
free:16763 slab_reclaimable:1340 slab_unreclaimable:2956
mapped:29 shmem:12 pagetables:11130 bounce:0
Node 0 DMA free:7892kB min:16kB low:20kB high:24kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15772kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 4024 14836 14836
Node 0 DMA32 free:47464kB min:4224kB low:5280kB high:6336kB active_anon:3848564kB inactive_anon:147080kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:8kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:4120800kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:60kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:28kB slab_unreclaimable:268kB kernel_stack:48kB pagetables:8604kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:82 all_unreclaimable? yes
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 10811 10811
Node 0 Normal free:11184kB min:11352kB low:14188kB high:17028kB active_anon:9906928kB inactive_anon:990904kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:1116kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):256kB present:11071436kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:56kB shmem:48kB slab_reclaimable:5332kB slab_unreclaimable:11556kB kernel_stack:2400kB pagetables:35916kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:32 all_unreclaimable? no
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Node 0 DMA: 3*4kB 1*8kB 2*16kB 1*32kB 0*64kB 3*128kB 1*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB 1*2048kB 1*4096kB = 7892kB
Node 0 DMA32: 62*4kB 104*8kB 53*16kB 29*32kB 27*64kB 7*128kB 2*256kB 3*512kB 1*1024kB 3*2048kB 8*4096kB = 47464kB
Node 0 Normal: 963*4kB 0*8kB 5*16kB 4*32kB 7*64kB 5*128kB 6*256kB 1*512kB 2*1024kB 1*2048kB 0*4096kB = 11292kB
318 total pagecache pages
0 pages in swap cache
Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
Free swap  = 0kB
Total swap = 0kB
3854801 pages RAM
86406 pages reserved
14574 pages shared
3738264 pages non-shared
```

Comment: It's not nginx itself which consumes the memory but your Ruby application (which apparently is run as part of your nginx process through e.g. passenger). Fiddling with nginx request settings won't help you here. Instead, you should check why your ruby application process increases its memory usage (e.g. because you have memory leaks, a non-optimal cache configuration, ...) or maybe you just have too many application instances configured and too little memory.